# Android :get an object from an inner class

Tags: android, inner-classes

I defined a broadcast receiver as an inner class .And i wan't to get an object from the receiver to the external class ,jut like this :

```
class External {
public object ;
class Inner {
object = something ;
getObject () { return object; }
}//end Inner class
method (){
Inner inn = new Inner();
inn.getObject(); //here i would like to get the object from inner class
}
}
```

But it doesent work for me , i'm gettin an empty object ,this is my real code :

```
public class Wifi extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
WifiManager wifi;
Button      enab;
String resultsString ; 
String[] myStringArray;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)){
            List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();

            resultsString = results.toString() ;

            //Log.i("resultsString",resultsString);
            List<WifiConfiguration> resultsConf = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();                 
        }
    }
            /*****  I would like to get resultsString *******/
    public String getResult(){
        return resultsString ;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi);
    ConnectivityManager cxMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
    /***** I would like to get resultsString in this method but I'm getting a null  **/

    registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
Log.i("receiver.getResult()",receiver.getResult()+"");  
}
}
```

And this is my logCat

```
03-27 12:28:51.947: I/receiver.getResult()(24524): null
```

Thank you .I home someone will help me :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

I guess your getting error in below line

```
Log.i("receiver.getResult()",receiver.getResult());
```

may be **receiver** is **null** so that you can check it like below add `""+`

```
Log.i("receiver.getResult()",""+receiver.getResult());
```

**EDIT:**

```
IntentFilter intentFilter =new IntentFilter(Receiver.ACTION_TEXT_CAPITALIZED);
intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
/* create new broadcast receiver*/
Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

Add this in your Receiver class

```
public final static String ACTION_TEXT_CAPITALIZED= "com.android.guide.exampleintentservice.intent.action.ACTION_TEXT_CAPITALIZED";
```

You can send information like below

```
Intent resultBroadCastIntent =new Intent();
resultBroadCastIntent.setAction(Receiver.ACTION_TEXT_CAPITALIZED);
resultBroadCastIntent.setAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
resultBroadCastIntent.setAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
resultBroadCastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
sendBroadcast(resultBroadCastIntent);
```

Comment: yess a null result ,but how to get the object in right way

Comment: he didn't recognize "TextCapitalizeResultReceiver" TextCapitalizeResultReceiver cannot be resolved to a variable